# How to troubleshoot Java applet inside firefox?

Tags: firefox, java

I have a requirement to digitally sign PDF files on a specific site. This site allows to do so via a java applet only. So installed an old firefox(52.9.0) which supports java plugin. Java applet is successfully loaded by the site, but is unable to find the hardware token (ePass2003) connected to USB port. Official binaries provided with this token are able to read it. How can I troubleshoot java applet(which probably seems to be the culprit here) or may be something else? Doing all this on a freshly installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

icedtea is not installed. Instead java is installed as per [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_plugin.html) and verified the java plugin installation by :-

1. Verifying the java version on java.com, it is found to be version 8 update 201. 64-bit java plugin is installed.
2. Similar results found via "about:plugins"

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep icedtea` to the question. Also visit the https://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp?detect=jre and share the screenshot of it.

Comment: Updated the question with java installation method and its version.

Comment: For more reproducible results I may recommend to use IcedTea instead of Oracle JRE. Something like `sudo apt install icedtea-plugin`.

Comment: Done. Replaced Oracle JRE plugin with IcedTea plugin. Now java version is 8 update 191.

Comment: The java applet no longer on IcedTea plugin. It fails to initialize. I suppose, troubleshooting Oracle JRE should be the way to find a solution. How to proceed here?

Comment: Then install JRE back and start over :) The problem may be really complicated. Maybe installing Windows on VirtualBox and accessing the token from it would be faster and more useful.

Comment: Yes, running windows in a VM is anyhow the last solution but I am trying to figure out if the token is accessible within linux. I do have official library file. Firefox is able to access the token via this lib file (under Security Devices) and even the official GUI binaries are able to access it. It's just that when java applet is loaded, it doesn't know how and where to pick this lib file in order to read the token and get the work done.

Comment: You may consider to try the latest build of Firefox ESR (Extended Support Release) - [52.9.0](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/). It should support Java plugin (I see that it supports, I write this from it).

Comment: My bad. I am already using the Firefox version 52.9.0. Edited the question with correct version.